# How can I get the Apache Camel Message History in logfile from log4j?

Tags: java, log4j, apache-camel, log4j2

in the [Apache Camel documantation](http://camel.apache.org/message-history.html) is a nice Message History. I want this for my errorHandler. So I do

```
errorHandler(
            deadLetterChannel("direct:deadLetter")
                .logExhaustedMessageHistory(true)
                .maximumRedeliveries(3)
                .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
                );
```

and also:

```
CamelContext context = getContext();
context.setMessageHistory(true);
```

But the nice Message History doesn't show, not in the Console and not in the Logfile. How can I activate this?

My log4j appenders is:

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy/MM/dd-HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C:%M:%L ~ %m%n"/>
    </Console>
...
```

I have search Google, but I only find the Information above and these don't work.

Thank you

EDIT:

This work, but I lost the deadLetterChannel. It is a bug?

```
errorHandler(
        defaultErrorHandler()
        .logExhausted(true)
        .logExhaustedMessageHistory(true)
        );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the Problem:

```
errorHandler(
        deadLetterChannel("direct:deadLetter")
            .maximumRedeliveries(3)
            .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
            );


from("direct:deadLetter").id("deadLetter")
    .routeId("deadLetter")
    .errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler().disableRedelivery())
    .process(new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange msg) {
            String MsgHist = org.apache.camel.util.MessageHelper.dumpMessageHistoryStacktrace(msg, new DefaultExchangeFormatter(), false);
            LOG.error(MsgHist, msg);
            msg.getOut().setBody(msg.getIn().getBody(Document.class));
            msg.getOut().setHeaders(msg.getIn().getHeaders());
            msg.getOut().setHeader("MessageHistory",MsgHist);
        }
    })
    .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR,"${exception.stacktrace}")
    .setHeader("ErrorMessage",simple("${exception}",String.class))
    .setHeader("ErrorStacktrace",simple("${exception.stacktrace}",String.class))
            .to("activemqWithoutTransactions:errors");
```

Yes it is a Bug:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8755
Solved in 2.16